# Testing an SNI https service by ip address

Tags: perl, ssl, lwp-useragent

I am writing a perl script to test out a server before switching DNS from the old server (for supporting server migrations).  I'd rather not hack /etc/hosts to override DNS for testing, and instead have the script munge things to work.

It's easy enough for non-ssl connections, but I'm having trouble with SSL - it works for most sites because most still bind a site to an ip address, but one particular customer's site is too smart for its own good (and that's the direction things should be heading anyhow), and I need to tell LWP::UserAgent to connect to an IP address but use a servername in the request (both SSL SNI and HTTP Host:).

I'm using ssl_opts to set the SNI hostname (and the SSLeay trace shows that's getting set right), and forcing the Host HTTP header to the servername (which printing out the request shows is supposed to be getting set right), but LWP uses the url to decide what host to connect to and that url is getting in where it shouldn't somewhere (I would expect the actual "GET" to be simply "GET /", so the request "as_string" isn't completely accurate here), resulting in an error:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#
#  ht
#
#  https test
#  see if I can force a Host: header
#  while using an ip address to connect
#

use strict;

use Net::SSLeay;
use LWP::UserAgent;
$Net::SSLeay::trace = 2;

my $ip = '1.2.3.4';
my $server_name = 'server.name';
my $url = "https://$ip/";
#my $url = "https://$server_name/";

print "connecting to $ip for $server_name\n";

my $h = HTTP::Headers->new;
$h->header('Host' => $server_name);

my %options = (
    'ssl_opts' => { SSL_hostname => $server_name }
);

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(%options);
$ua->agent("perl-mpchk/0.1 ");

# Create a request
my $req;
$req = HTTP::Request->new('GET', $url, $h);
print $req->as_string, "\n";

# Send request to the user agent and get a response back
my $res = $ua->request($req);
if (!defined($res)) {
    die "connect to $url failed\n";
}

print $res->status_line, "\n";

exit 0;
```

with a hostname:

```
connecting to 1.2.3.4 for server.name
GET https://server.name/
Host: server.name

DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:562: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:564: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:586: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:619: using SNI with hostname server.name
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:654: request OCSP stapling
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:673: set socket to non-blocking to enforce timeout=180
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:699: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:709: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:729: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:744: ssl handshake done
200 OK
```

with an ip address

```
connecting to 1.2.3.4 for server.name
GET https://1.2.3.4/
Host: server.name

DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:562: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:564: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:586: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:619: using SNI with hostname server.name
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:654: request OCSP stapling
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:673: set socket to non-blocking to enforce timeout=180
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:699: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:709: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:729: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:744: ssl handshake done
500 Unknown Domain
```

Answer (score 2):

You might skip LWP and use the socket directly:

```
use IO::Socket::SSL;

my $ip_address = ...;
my $server_name = ...;

my $cl = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
    PeerAddr => $ip_address,
    PeerPort => 443,
    SSL_hostname => $server_name,
    SSL_verifycn_name => $server_name,
    SSL_verifycn_scheme => 'http',
);
print $cl "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: $server_name\r\n\r\n";
print scalar(<$cl>);  # status line
```

Comment: That gets the same error, and tshark shows SNI being set properly, so I think the problem is actually a server interaction issue.  I'm pursuing that with the remote site now...

Answer (score -1):

The problem turned out to be a proxy in the middle that was translating to an IP address url form.  Corrected to properly use the name and it started working.

Comment: Your  question asked about how to test a specific IP address with SNI. Your answer does not answer the question but instead shows the solution to the underlying problem, i.e. why you needed this test at all. Thus it would be a fit for a comment, but not for an answer.